# How can I follow the instant changes of certain data in the database with SignalR?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I am using a SQL Server database, I am connecting with code-first method in my .NET Core project. I have a table named `Order` in the database. In this table, how can I instantly print the orders of the number I have taken as a parameter with SignalR.

I tried to create a Hub and connect but couldn't

```
 public class OrderHub:Hub
{
    private readonly OrdeContext _dbContext;

    public OrderHub(OrdeContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task SendReadyOrders(int orderId)
    {
        var readyOrders = await _dbContext.Orders
            .Where(o => o.Id == orderId)
            .ToListAsync();

        
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveReadyOrders", readyOrders);
    }
}
```

db link code

```
  services.AddDbContext<OrdeContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Local"));
        });
```

client code

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:5097/orderHub")
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On("ReceiveReadyOrders", (string message) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ready orders received: {message}");
            
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("SignalR connection established.");

        
        int orderId = 1;

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendReadyOrders", orderId);

        Console.ReadLine();

        await hubConnection.StopAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("SignalR connection stopped.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already register your database into the DI like below, then you could directly using the dbcontext inside the hubs.

Like below:

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
    options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")); },
    ServiceLifetime.Scoped
);
```

Hubs:

```
  private YourDbContext dbContext;

  public ChatHub(YourDbContext dbContext)
  {
       this.dbContext = dbContext;
  }

  public void YourMethod()
  {
       //call the dbContext here to get the data by the parameter and then send it to the client
  }
```

Comment: I updated the question, added the code snippets. Unfortunately, when I try to connect, status shows as disconnected.

Comment: Could you please tell me your asp.net core version?

Comment: .Net Core 7.0.8